# Why is this div completely broken?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea whats going on here. Have a form contained in a div, and the div has a background color.

It works on one part of my website, but just doesn't work at all on another. Here's a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcyaahnw/) of whats going on

Also the affected code posted here:

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

.submit-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.input-half {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.input-half-2 {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}


.contact-contain {
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-back {
  width: 100%;
}

#back-img {
  width: 100%
}

.cont-textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-contain" id="link-c"><br>
  <h1>Contact Over The Horizon:</h1><br><br>
  <form>
    <div class="input-half">
      <label for="contname">Your Name</label><br>
      <input class="input-box" type="text" name="contname"><br>
      <label for="eaddress">Your Email</label><br>
      <input class="input-box" type="text" name="eaddress"><br>
      <label for="subj">Message Subject</label><br>
      <input class="input-box" type="text" name="subj">
    </div>
    <div class="input-half-2">
      <label for="contactmsg">Message Content</label><br><br>
      <textarea class="cont-textarea"></textarea><br><br>
      <button class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submitq" value="Send"><span>Submit Quote</span></button><br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. What does "completely broken" and "doesn't work" mean here?

Comment: Just FYI, it's better to use padding and margins to create space than it is to throw in a bunch of `br` tags. `<br>` makes revisions later *much* more difficult and time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: You want your div to contain your form (which has zero height). Do this:

```
.contact-contain {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kcyaahnw/4/)**

Comment: How can a form have zero height when it doesn't?? This worked but I don't understand why it worked.

Comment: @ZachCurtis If you open your browser's developer tools and hover over the `<form>` element with element highlighting turned on, you'll see that `<form>` on your JSFiddle is a zero-height element.

Comment: Give "clearfix" a Google. It's a common problem with floated and other elements. There are several zillion such questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me you will get better with time, but I think, to achieve what you want you can simply set a custom body background-color like this

```
body {background-color: lightgray;}
```

and you should be good

Comment: This assumes that the OP wants the entire page to be colored. That's not a safe bet.

Comment: Actually the questioner seems like a beginner so I don't think it's a good idea to confuse him with something new so he won't use it the wrong way, I say this because I'm a beginner too. But you're very correct thanks anyway!